# Chart Return Unassigned Line Colour

Tags: c#, forms, charts, colors, line

Q: Is there some way to return the line colour assigned automatically to a series as seen on the line chart?

When charting a `Series` in `C#` (`.NET 4.6.1`) Forms Line Chart and a colour is not explicitly assigned to a Series using `Chart1.Series["x"].Color`, a default colour is assigned somewhere automatically. How do you return this colour?

I have used Red here to differentiate the initial first series default colour from my assigned colour. Orange to see if I had the wrong property.

I have reconstructed the problem in a simplified chart.

I have tested the `BorderColor` property as `BorderWidth` is the line width of a Line Chart but the use of `Color` property is what actually sets a different line colour in code. So, I assume the correct Property is `Color`.

If I set a colour using `Series["x"].Color = Color.Red;` then `Series["x"].Color` returns Red and the colour of the line on the chart is also Red.

I have separated the request from the creation using a fancy button to be certain this was not an issue with the request for Color happening before the chart is drawn.

My assumption is `Chart` is assigning this outside of the Properties of a Series likely in reaction to `Series.Colour` being [Empty]. Why Chart? Because the automatically assigned colours blue, orange etc occur in the same order and are assigned to series in this order regardless of ChartArea. The first Added Series is always blue the second orange etc.

```
int[] seriesData = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  };
int[] seriesX = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Area1");
    //chart1.ChartAreas["Area1"].CursorX.Interval = 1;
    Series series = new Series("Data");
    chart1.Series.Add("Data");
    chart1.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series["Data"].BorderWidth = 2;
    //chart1.Series["Data"].BorderColor = Color.Red;
    //chart1.Series["Data"].Color = Color.Orange;
    chart1.Series["Data"].Points.DataBindXY(seriesX, seriesData);
}

private void Btn_GetColour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Series Colours\r\nBorder Colour: " + chart1.Series["Data"].BorderColor + "\r\nColor: " + chart1.Series["Data"].Color);
}
```

When not explicitly setting `Chart1.Series["x"].Color` and an automatically assigned colour is used `Chart1.Series["x"].Color` does not return the colour shown on the chart. Instead it returns [Empty].

Expecting some sort of blue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the automatic colors you need to call `Chart.ApplyPaletteColors` first..:

> MSDN: When the Chart colors are automatically assigned at run time, there is
>   no way to know what the colors will be prior to the time when the
>   chart rendered; the Color property of an automatically assigned value
>   will return Empty at this time.
>
> If you call the ApplyPaletteColors method, the colors for the series
>   and the data points will be set, which allows for programmatic access.

Comment: Thank you TaW, that is exactly what I was missing! I don't have enough user points to bump this response up but hopefully someone else can. Cheers!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..